# UMBRACO: Surface Controller and Dynamic Template

Tags: asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, umbraco

I am new to Umbraco. I have a question in its documentation regarding Surface Controller, please see this link https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/routing/surface-controllers/

What those statements (highlighted in yellow) means?
[image]

Here are my sample codes

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Cache;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Logging;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Routing;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Web;
using Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence;
using Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Attributes;
using Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Controllers;
using Umbraco.Cms.Web.Website.Controllers;
using UmbracoTest.Infrastructure;
using UmbracoTest.Model;

namespace UmbracoTest.Controllers
{
  public class SectionOptionsController : SurfaceController
  {
    public SectionOptionsController(IUmbracoContextAccessor umbracoContextAccessor, 
    IUmbracoDatabaseFactory databaseFactory, ServiceContext services, AppCaches 
    appCaches, IProfilingLogger profilingLogger, IPublishedUrlProvider 
    publishedUrlProvider) : base(umbracoContextAccessor, databaseFactory, services, 
    appCaches, profilingLogger, publishedUrlProvider)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DummyModel>> GetAllDataFromDBAsync()
    {
        //returns list of data
    }
   }
 }
```

When I tried to trigger it in Postman it returns 404.
I am expecting a list will be returned.
Here is the url I used in Postman, https://localhost:44327/Umbraco/surface/SectionOptions/GetAllDataFromDBAsync.

Also, may I request for a high level suggestion on how to implement the below scenario.

**Scenario:**

-There is a button in UI, and I am planning to make it dynamic. This button will be used in different content page.
-If this is clicked, it will display a table that contains data from our database.
-This dynamic button will accept an id/flagging that determines what set of data will be displayed in the UI.
-For the id/flagging I am planning that this will be populated by the content editor. Depending on the set data needed in each content page.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SurfaceControllers are made to work with Html Form posts.  If you want to retrieve data, you should use [UmbracoApiControllers](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/routing/umbraco-api-controllers).
These will route to `~/Umbraco/Api/[YourControllerName]`

The API controller is what I guess you want with your scenario. If you show this table with javascript.
If you are rendering the table serverside on a page, consider using [RenderControllers](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/routing/custom-controllers)